# Backbone event firing on click OR press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am new to backbone and I am looking for a way for my button to be triggered when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well as clicking. Currently `showPrompt` only executes on a click. What is the cleanest DRYest way to have it execute on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well, preferably only for that input field.

```
(function () {

  var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name: null
  });

  var Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function (models, options) {
      this.bind("add", options.view.addFriendLi);
    }
  });

  var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function() {
      this.friends = new Friends(null, {view: this});
    },
    events: {
      "click #add-friend":  "showPrompt",
    },
    showPrompt: function () {
      var friend_name = $("#friend-name").val()
      var friend_model = new Friend({ name:friend_name });
      this.friends.add( friend_model );
    },
    addFriendLi: function (model) {
      $("#friends-list").append("<li>" + model.get('name') + "</li>");
    }
  });

  var appView = new AppView; 

}());
```

Also where can I read more about this kind of event binding? Do backbone events differ from JS or jQuery events in how they're defined?

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that you are using `jQuery` for `DOM manipulation`, you can create your own "tiny" plugin that fires the <kbd>Enter</kbd> event in the inputs. Put it in your `plugins.js` or whatever setup scripts file you have:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    $(this).trigger('enter');
  }
});
```

Now that you have created this "enter" plugin, you can listen to enter events this way:

```
events: {
  "click #add-friend": "showPrompt",
  "enter #friend-name": "showPrompt"
}
```

Comment: Or, if you want it to work on any element (not just input), you can do something like the following for the jQuery snippet:

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(':focus').trigger('enter');
        }
    });

Answer (score 19):

You can add one more `event` to your `events` hash in `AppView`.

```
events: {
   "click #add-friend":  "showPrompt",
   "keyup #input-field-id" : "keyPressEventHandler"
}
```

Where `#input-field-id` is the one you want to add event on.

Then add `eventHandler` in `AppView`.

```
keyPressEventHandler : function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        this.$("#add-friend").click();
    }
}
```

NOTE : This code is not tested but you can think doing it in this way.

Have a look at [this](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-127) to understand how `Backbone` handles `events` in a `View`.

Comment: So I need to have two different functions? Keypress evennt handler and  the show prompt.. hm guess that's okay, doesn't seem very DRY though

Comment: You can think of calling `showPrompt` again on `keyup` with a check for `keyCode`.

Comment: Instead of triggering a `click` event on an `#add-friend`, simply calling `this.showPrompt()` would be enough.

Comment: @Timofey what issue are you facing with this approach?

Comment: it simply didn't trigger the event for me, I spent some time trying to get it to work. I must have missed something, I can go back and try again sometime soon