# Submitting a form which does not have a form tag by pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, backbone.js

I'm using WordPress Liveblog:

https://github.com/Automattic/liveblog

My aim is to let the user submit a form without the need to click submit. Instead, I'd like the form to be submitted using the enter key.

**My form** can be seen here:
https://github.com/Automattic/liveblog/blob/master/templates/liveblog-form.php

You will see the form doesn't have a `form` tag. Instead the form `input` is contained within `script` tags. So, I can't use the jQuery submit method e.g. `$('#formID').submit();`

I *think* backbone.js is used? I'm unfamiliar with how backbone.js works.

How can I let users submit this particular form by pressing the enter key?

Comment: So how do you submit a form if there is no form to submit? Why don't you ad a form?

Comment: I think my use of the word 'form' is too loose. I don't think a 'form' is submitted, rather, information on the page (the contents of the textarea) is submitted or 'communicated'. Does that explain it better? Should I update the wording in my question? thanks, Henry

Comment: My aim is to send the contents of the textarea on it's way by pressing enter. hope that make it a little clearer what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20382746/1709033) did the job. The snippet:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
      $(this).trigger('enter');
   }
 });
```